# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels' even after rechecking that i have installed the package

Tags: django, django-models, django-channels

there is an issue with my packages, i have installed django channels(just channels) using pip install channels command and when i tried to run server command i just got an error sayinh the module not found but when i run the command

```
pip list | grep channels
```

there are two modules installed

```
channels                            2.1.6
channels-redis                      2.3.3
```

i dont know the reason behind the error 
can somone help me figure out if i have done anything wrong

i have added them in insalled app section of settings.py

full traceback

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x0458E780>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 112, in i
nner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exceptio
n
    raise _exception[1]

  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 89, in populate
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Users\madhumani\workspace\ven\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'channels'
```

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback with line numbers?

Comment: question has been updated please have a look

Comment: Did you set the `ASGI_APPLICATION` variable in settings.py or create a default routing application?  Look at https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html for more installation info.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. I just exec `pip install channels` and it worked.

Comment: You can make your inline text appear as code by using backticks (`).